# Errors for changing variables content depending on session status

Tags: php, mysql, session, variables

I am trying to write a script that changes a veriables content depending on there session status and what ID that was in the URL of the page (e.g www.example.com/profile.php?id=1) so it would display one set of content if they arnt logged in and viewing someone elses profile, another if there logged in and on there own profile, and another if there logged in and viewing someone elses profile.

Firstly the script gets the ID from the url:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
     $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); // filter everything but numbers
} else if (isset($_SESSION['idx'])) {
     $id = $logOptions_id;
} else {
   header("location: index.php");
   exit();
}
```

Then it runs some other code i wont include, then this code:

```
// ------- DECIDES WHAT TO DISOPLAY, DEPENDING ON VERIABLES ---------

if (isset($_SESSION['idx']) && $logOptions_id == $id) { // If session is set and ID matches the profiles ID
$content = ""Your viewing your own profile";

} else if (isset($_SESSION['idx']) && $logOptions_id != $id) { // If SESSION is set, but ID dosent match profiles ID
$follow_option = "Your viewing someone elses profile";


} else {
$content = "Your are not logged in";
}
// ------- END DECIDES WHAT TO DISOPLAY, DEPENDING ON VERIABLES ---------


print $content;
```

Now to my problem, all it does is display the option for being logged in and viewing someone elses profile "Your viewing someone elses profile". If you see any errors that would lead to this, please answer below. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams your variables don't hold the expected values when the `$logOptions_id != $id` runs, or you either forget to start the session. I don't see reference where $logOptions_id gets assigned. Use your IDE tool to debug the code.